# How to deal with "Brown on" slowly increasing voltage/current from solar panel to power mcu

Tags: arduino, power-supply, power, atmel, solar-energy

With a solar panel powering an Atsamd21, I have the problem that the mcu will not boot correctly and gets stuck at some point.

How can I deal with this? I thought of adding a large enough capacitor and some kind of voltage detection to enable power only when the cap reaches a certain voltage. This will restart the mcu until power is large enough, but at least it won't get stuck from slowly increasing voltage.

Comment: You can use an undervoltage detector ic to check whether the input voltage, in this case the voltage across the intput capacitor, is high enough. There are some cheap ics out there like the LM8364, which can be used to drive the `reset` pin of your MCU.

Comment: voltage supervisor IC

Comment: One issue with powering an MCU from a solar panel is that the current will be low until the processor is executing, the voltage will drop and the processor go into reset starting the cycle again. It can often then cycle on and off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SAMD21 contains a power-on-reset (POR) and brown-out detector (BOD) circuitry. Depending on the settings they may not be in use by default, so you may have to specifically enable them. Otherwise you have to use an external voltage supervisor IC to keep the SAMD21 in reset until supply voltage is high enough.

Note that the SAMD21 can work down to 1.62 V supply voltage, but it certainly can't work at maximum speed with minimum voltage, so you need to check either how large supply voltage you need for your current clock speed, or how fast the clock can be with the given supply voltage you have.